# i m trying to create a code in python to send files from a folder in google drive every time new file is added to telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram

```
import os
import requests
import time
import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Set up Google Drive API client
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:\\Users\\HOME\\Desktop//credentials.json')
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Set up Telegram bot
bot_token = '#####'
chat_id = '-####'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)

# Set up the folder ID for the Google Drive folder you want to monitor
folder_id = '#####'

# Define a function to send a message to Telegram
def send_message(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error sending message: {e}")

# Define a function to download a file from Google Drive and send it to Telegram
def download_file(file_id):
    try:
        file = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
        filename = file['name']
        url = file['webContentLink']
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=open(filename, 'rb'))
        os.remove(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error downloading file: {e}")

# Define a function to monitor the specified folder for new files
def monitor_folder():
    try:
        response = drive_service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed = false",
                                              orderBy='createdTime desc').execute()
        files = response.get('files', [])
        print(response)
        for file in files:
            created_time = datetime.fromisoformat(file['createdTime'][:-1] + '+00:00')
            # Process only new files
            if datetime.utcnow() - created_time < timedelta(minutes=1):
                send_message(f"New file added to Google Drive: {file['name']}")
                download_file(file['id'])
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error monitoring folder: {e}")

# Define the main function to run the program
def main():
    while True:
        monitor_folder()
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got this code from some source and have been testing it in visual studio code.
I have tested this in visual code and getting the error below

getting error monitoring  createdtime.

the api is interacting and response is also getting generated.
{'kind': 'drive#fileList', 'incompleteSearch': False, 'files': [{'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14vdzV4UotlXE5Dl5P_BDemUQW0VWJPTG', 'name': '201512742_Accord Cotton LLP_1-May-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14uV5DMD4eJJrco7gaRjijrDugXOH9pPT', 'name': '201512741_BADRI ECO FIBRE PVT. LTD_30-Apr-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14srUuBJck6I9a0TICUqK4rrXLsheoSno', 'name': '201512740_Patil Rail Infrastructure Pvt Ltd_30-Apr-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14qyowsCpXU-j1rW3QL8zX9UbeKfia_VO', 'name': '201512739_Badri Cotsyn Pvt. Ltd._29-Apr-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14pJa4TvfzUioEdFeltgrXQb7hUjB8J6D', 'name': '201512738_VARUN BEVARAGES LIMITED_29-Apr-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14ok0vGEvRvbrd4TaTYswkww-2y6PuFlT', 'name': '201512737_Badri Cotsyn Pvt. Ltd._28-Apr-23.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14lpUDjwt2Nt-Es7zT4zGRc1TtFggVjCG', 'name': '48_Shree Krishna Packaging_5-May-23 - Copy - Copy.pdf'}, {'kind': 'drive#file', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'id': '14jfp4gj8X216GoaDRnhWOOshe324KTHZ', 'name': '48_Shree Krishna Packaging_5-May-23 - Copy.pdf'}]}

please help to correct this code